# Error of adding row into UITableView with animation

Tags: ios, uitableview

I use this to add rows to my UITableView with animation :

```
[bookMarksArray insertObject:infoDict atIndex:0];
NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[bookMarksArray count] inSection:0];
[bookMarkTable insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

when i call `[bookMarkTable reloadData]` all works fine. But if i try to use previous code my app crashes with error : attempt to insert row 1 into section 0, but there are only 1 rows in section 0 after the update . Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `[bookMarksArray count] - 1` when creating the index path (its 0 indexed).

Comment: He inserted the object at index 0. So your solution isn't quite right. The table will insert a row at the bottom of the table and it will be a duplicate of the previous last row since it maps to the same object at the end of the data model array.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance Timothy, I'm so used to seeing `addObject:` that I missed that point entirely.

Answer (score 1):

@Jonathan's explanation for the exception is correct. But the solution is still wrong. You've inserted an object at index 0, so the index path of the inserted row would be:

```
NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
```

If you had inserted the object at the end of the array, you would do

```
NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[bookMarksArray count] - 1 inSection:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to update numberOfRows before call insertRowsAtIndexPath.